# cannot delete db table

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.6

I tried to use a DROP statement to delete a table but I could not.Instead I tried the following....I deleted the `.frm` and `.ibd` files from of the respective table from the directory.

Then I used a create statement from a backup file to recreate the table...and the weird thing is that I get message saying that the table already exists (despite having deleted the aforementioned files)...

After the create statement the directory has again the `.ibd` file.

I do not know what to do or assume.

Comment: whats the error message you received  when you executed `drop table x;`

Comment: unfortunately I cannot remember...in the panic I forgot it...I have this problem for hours and it appeared out of nowhere.

Comment: Can you run `SHOW CREATE TABLE tblname \G` on the table right now ???

Comment: this is the code SHOW CREATE TABLE appointments.business_users \G; appointments is the database....I get a syntax warning #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\G' at line 1

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is now. Do you have access to the table or not? Does `select * from table;` work or not? Do you want to `drop` the table and you get an error?

Comment: Can you run `SHOW CREATE TABLE appointments.business_users;` and post the exact output in the question (even if it is an error message)?

Comment: If write select *... from I get message saying that the table does not exist.If I go to create though a table with the exact same name I get the following message:1814 tablespace for table tblname exists.disregard the tablespace before import

Comment: @ypercube  here is the message I get in the above statement:#1146 - Table 'appointments.business_users' doesn't exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First have a look at the InnoDB Architecture (from Percona CTO Vadim Tkachenko)

[image: InnoDB Plumbing]

Your problem is very simple. You have a broken data dictionary entry. Inside the system tablespace file `ibdata1` is a list of tablespace ids.

There is an entry for `appointments.business_users`. Deleting the `.frm` and `.ibd` of `appointments.business_users` does not remove its tablespace id from the data dictionary. You need to remove that entry from the data dictionary.

The reason you are getting the error still ? Although you can the `CREATE TABLE` and generated the `.frm` and `.ibd` file, the tablespace id in the `.ibd` file does not match the original tablespace id in the data dictionary.

Here are some old posts on how to repair it in place

- From @akuzminsky : [InnoDB issue after power outage a few weeks ago - no backup](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/70002/innodb-issue-after-power-outage-a-few-weeks-ago-no-backup/70003#70003)
- From @DerekDowney : [ERROR Cannot find or open table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25036/error-cannot-find-or-open-table/25053#25053)
- From me : [restore table from .frm and .ibd file?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16875/mysql-how-to-restore-table-stored-in-a-frm-and-a-ibd-file/16911#16911)

If the database isn't too big, you could do the following:

- mysqldump everything EXCEPT `appointments.business_users`
- drop all databases (except mysql schema)
- shutdown mysql
- delete ibdata1
- start mysql (recreated ibdata1)
- reload the mysqldump
- manually run the `CREATE TABLE` command for `appointments.business_users`

Either way, you have some homework to do.

Comment: How am I going to open ibdata1...I tried with notepad and the program crashes.

Comment: ibdata1 is a binary file. You cannot manipulate with a text editor. Look at the diagram. There are many moving parts within ibdata1. There is no text manipulation available.

Comment: No, no, no, you do not open that file. **No**. (**ΟΧΙ**, apropos ;)

Comment: And the real take-home from all of this is: Don't delete `.frm` and `.ibd` files by hand.

Comment: ok...I do not open ibdata1...how am I going to remove the ID from the data dictionary....read the posts?

Comment: what might have caused this issue...so as to avoid it in the future...I have to find out the causes also.

Comment: I completely dropped the database and the import my backup...that solved it

Comment: I have the same problem agai....so it is important to find out what is causing it

Comment: here is the cause of the problem PROBABLY https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68148